# How do I properly do collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm developing a Mario Kart fangame in Unity as a project for a course I'm taking. I have to add laps, but the collision, no matter what kind of lines I use, doesn't work! Please help me here, I'm quite the newbie as you can tell.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
   {
       if (checkpointHit1 = false)
       {
           if (collision.gameObject.tag == "CP1")
           {
               checkpointHit1 = true;
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: `if (checkpointHit1 = false)` is an assignment, should be `if (!checkpointHit1)`

Comment: What exactly is this code on.   What settings do you have on the colliders. You need to share more than its not working if you corrected the if statement

Comment: This is being used on a KartController I saw a tutorial of online, I'm trying to enter through a trigger

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `=` only once by mistake, which causes an assignment instead of a comparison.
You should write:

```
if (checkpointHit1 == false)
```